# How to avoid mutating a prop directly when all you have is a click?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I mutate a prop the correct way, so that I don't get the *[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly* message?

I already got the v-model to work on this v-dialog. However, I also want to provide a close button in the dialog itself, which causes this mutation warning, as it's the dialog itself that's mutating the variable. How best to approach this case and solve it?

Dialog.vue:

```
<template>
    <v-dialog
        :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event)"
        scrollable
        width="80vw"
        :transition="false"
    >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <div v-on="on" @click="$emit('open')">
                <slot name="button">
                    <v-btn color="primary">{{ buttonText == null ? title : buttonText }}</v-btn>
                </slot>
            </div>
        </template>
        <v-card
            elevation="10"
            height="80vh"
        >
            <v-system-bar
                color="light-blue darken-3"
                window
            >
                <span>{{title}}</span>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-icon @click="value=false">mdi-close</v-icon>
            </v-system-bar>
            <v-card-text> <!-- required here to make the scrollable v-dialog work -->
                <slot></slot>
            </v-card-text>
            <slot name="actions"></slot>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            title: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            buttonText: String,
            value: Boolean,
        },
    }
</script>
```

I can use it quite nicely like:

```
<mydialog title="Select something" button-text="A button!" v-model="dialog" @open="loadData()">
  Content goes here...
</mydialog>
```

The `<v-icon @click="value=false">mdi-close</v-icon>` is what's incorrectly mutating the "value"-variable.

Sidenote #1: The open event is there so I can populate data (loadData) from a database when the dialog is opened (vs. when its created on the DOM).

**UPDATE;** I can get it to work by doing:

```
<v-icon @click="$emit('close', $event)">mdi-close</v-icon>
```

and

```
<mydialog title="Select something" button-text="A button!" v-model="dialog" @open="loadData()" @close="dialog=false">
```

However, I feel this is far from being elegant. Aren't there any solutions in where I don't need to add on-Handlers to close this dialog? I almost feel that this is worse than living with the warning.. :|

Comment: $emit value instead

Comment: If you want to modify the value inherited from the parent, you should simple do `this.$emit('input', false)` when closing the dialog. This maintains the two-way binding without mutating the prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a computed property with get and set. The dialog computed will behave exactly as a normal variable and it will eliminate the warning. Now you can use it to get the value and also to set the value.

Try this:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    :value="dialog"
    @input="$emit('input', $event)"
    scrollable
    width="80vw"
    :transition="false"
  >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <div v-on="on" @click="dialogOpened()">
        <slot name="button">
          <v-btn color="primary">{{ buttonText == null ? title : buttonText }}</v-btn>
        </slot>
      </div>
    </template>
    <v-card elevation="10" height="80vh">
      <v-system-bar color="light-blue darken-3" window>
        <span>{{title}}</span>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-icon @click="dialog=false">mdi-close</v-icon>
      </v-system-bar>
      <v-card-text>
        <!-- required here to make the scrollable v-dialog work -->
        <slot></slot>
      </v-card-text>
      <slot name="actions"></slot>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
export default {
        props: ['title', 'buttonText', 'value'],      
        data: () => ({
          dlg_close: false,
        }), 
        computed: {
          dialog: {
            get() {
              return this.value;
            },
            set(selection) {
              this.$emit("input", selection);
            }
          }
        },
        methods: {
            dialogOpened(newVal) {
                this.dialog = newVal;
            },
        },

    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Hadn't seen these getters and setters in action before... time to read  up on those.. :)

Comment: @svenema start here bro: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter